# How to create bash script that will work on systems where bash is not installed in /bin/bash

Tags: bash

On systems like HP-UX or FreeBSD bash is installed in different locations, like /usr/local/bin/bash, so putting

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Will result in shell saying "script_name: not found"

Is there any workaround that would make shell script portable?

Comment: You can change shebang to `#!/usr/bin/env bash`

Comment: The idea is to use `#!/usr/bin/env bash` if you are not sure to which path `bash` is installed to.

Comment: You may want to have a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29608/why-is-it-better-to-use-usr-bin-env-name-instead-of-path-to-name-as-my - It may answer your question.